# Multiple Deletion

Tags: database, codeigniter, checkbox

Could anyone tell me any tricks on how to delete multi-rows in a database?

Like for example, I have these, *UPDATE* prior to suggestion, are there any mistakes?

```
    <table border='4' cellpadding='5'>

<th>Delete</th>
<th>Update</th>
<th>Book ID</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Released Year</th>
<th>ISBN</th>

<?php
if(isset($books)) 
{
foreach($books as $book)
    {
?>      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="idsToDelete[]" value="<?=$book['book_id']?>" /><td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo anchor("bookstore/delete/1",$book['book_name']) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_author'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_year'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['book_isbn'] ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
}
else
{
?>

<h2>No records</h2>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

All I want is that I have checkbox before the rows to be displayed and when I check them and click the submit those rows would be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
In **view:**

```
<?php
foreach($books as $each){
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="idsToDelete[]" value="<?=$each['id']?>" />
<?php    
}
?>
```

Now in the **Controller** you will recieve an array of ids, so simply delete the ids

```
<?php
if($this->input->post('idsToDelete')){
    $this->model->delete();
}
?>
```

In **Model**

```
<?php
function delete(){
    $idsToDelete    = $this->input->post('idsToDelete');
    $this->db->where_in('id', $idsToDelete)->delete('table');
}
?>
```

Comment: Dont i need to use if statements to determine whether the checkboxes are checked?

Comment: Thats the client side `js` checking do you need that as well? If yes,then try reading about validation of `checkboxes`.

Comment: Would you kindly examine my updated code if i did it correctly?

Comment: looks good to me, let me know if you face any problem. :D @user1891608

Comment: Appreciate your help, will try it out.. hopefully no hindrance :)

Comment: I have done it. 

Thanks for the help!. Im new to CI. No discussions really, professor just gave us activities right away. Need introductions on how to manipulate and pass variabls through this framework. i get confused sometimes

Comment: A question though, what is the syntax if i use it with an <a href> tag

for example,

<td><a href="localhost/bookstore/index.php/bookstore/update_form.php?id<?=$book['book_id']?>">Update</a></td>

Comment: `<td><a href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/bookstore/controller/method/<?=$book['book_id']?>">Update</a></td>`. Now in controller define your method and recieve the id as `$id = $this->uri->segment(3)`.

Comment: I was hoping not being able to use the uri method or the anchor method as i tried that earlier and it passed the whole thing i typed not the value i intended. Though, i think it was my mistake.. I guess ill have to work my way around it this time.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was planning to link that url to a form where in i put textboxes for the update but i included the id so i can echo the original or current data on said rows as to update them..

That would need me to create 2 files for updating, ive thought of a remedy. i can use it like this right?

<td><input type="text" name="bkname" value="<?php echo $book['book_id'] ?>"/></td>

-This is from the query above, i just echo the results inside textboxes wherein a user can just rename them there and click update to update. Is it okay? or is it prohibited?